# How do I select which OS to boot with no keyboard on a laptop? Can I adjust GRUB loader settings from the booted Ubuntu OS?

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, keyboard, bootloader

Well, the title says it all, basically. I am dual booting Windows 7 and Ubuntu 13.04 on my laptop, that has no keyboard. I am wondering how I would go about switching to Windows 7 (Ubuntu is the first option, and automatically boots after the countdown is done) if I can't use the up/down arrows.
Thanks.

Comment: Do you want to change the default OS?