# Keep timeout counting in grub 2 even if a key was pressed

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, tablet

I have surface 3

In surface 3 I can use the volume buttons for up and down, but there is no button for enter

I want to be able to choose between linux or windows without needing a keyboard. So I want the timeout to keep counting and when it finishes it boots to the selected entry automatically.

Is this possible in grub 2 ?

Comment: Once I asked the same for a Slate https://askubuntu.com/questions/642370/how-to-choose-which-os-to-start-in-dual-boot-with-touch-screen-and-no-physical-k and I am yet waiting for answers.